# Studied vs Studied About

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I was wondering what reads better.

1. Buddhism is a religion I’ve studied in school.
2. Buddhism is a religion I've studied about in school.

I think (1) reads better because, but when I say it, I want to put the "about" in there for some reason.

Comment: Did you learn _about_ Buddhism, or did you actually study to become a Buddhist?  The two are very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. is perfect.

You can *read* about a subject, *learn* about it, *hear* about it, *think* about it or *laugh* about it, but you can't *study about* anything! *Study* is transitive in this context, so it takes a direct object.